# Can I use zipline gem to download from s3 without model associations with paperclip or carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, zip, zipline

I want to allow my user to download a bundle of files that are stored on s3 using the zipline gem.  The files are already hosted on an s3 server but they aren't there as part of a paperclip or carrierwave attachment in my app.  Will I need to create some records in my database to sort of trick zipline into thinking they are paperclip attachments, or is there a way I can send the zip file without bothering with an attachment gem?  At the moment, trying to download the files with zipline doesn't throw an error message at all.  It just seems to skip right over and nothing downloads.

Answer (score 0):

See the part of the zipline README where an enumerator gets used to include remote files into the ZIP. It uses absolute URLs, to generate those from your S3 objects you will need to use presigned URLs (which Zipline is going to pass on to Curb):

`Aws::S3::Bucket.new(your_bucket_name).object(your_key).presigned_url(:get)`